# Date parameter not enclosed in quotes in SSMS-generated script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have this stored procedure:

```
....
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalenderPreload]
@startingSunday date,
@numberOfYears int

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @s DATE = DATEADD(year, @numberOfYears, @startingSunday);
.....
```

And I am trying to execute it using the `Execute Stored Procedure...` menu option of the context menu when right-clicking the procedure in the Object Explorer in SSMS.

I get this error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

This is the script that SSMS generates when I execute the procedure:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CalenderPreload]
    @startingSunday = 20151227, -- notice no ' '
    @numberOfYears = 5

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

For some reason my date is not being wrapped in quotes.

E: Apparently `datetime` passes the quotes whereas `date` does not?

Comment: Date should be passed in apostrophes: `@startingSunday = '2015-12-27' `

Comment: This isn't a problem with your procedure, it is a problem in how you are calling it.

Comment: `20151227` isn't a date. it's just an integer that to a human **LOOKS** like a date. to sqlserver, it's just an integer.

Comment: i tried `2015-12-27` and i got this error `Incorrect syntax near '-'.`, and againmy params arent being wrapped in quotes.

Comment: that's because you are still passing them without single quotes

Comment: hmm so i need to acutally put the quotes in the param?

Comment: How are you calling this stored procedure? That is where the problem most likely is.

Comment: @jeff rightclick in sql ->`execute stored procedure`

Comment: If you are right-clicking your stored procedure and clicking "Execute", then I am unable to reproduce your issue.   When I put a value like 20160101 in the value for a datetime column, the sql that gets generated is @Date='20160101'.   The quotes are added in automatically.  I don't know why it isn't happening for you.  What if you change the datatype of your parameter from `Date` to `Datetime`

Comment: it appears to me that `datetime` adds the quote and `date` doesnt. is that normal? i believe im using `date` somewhere else and this never came up

Comment: @lizzy81 Why you don't just press `Ctrl+N` and copy/paste the code?

Comment: @IvanSivak there are all kinds of ways to work around this, but I think lizzy is looking for an answer to the question "why?", and it's a valid question.   Lizzy, it may be a bug in your version of SQL.  You might try raising this on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: uhm, how do i handle this question. do i delete it or just leave it up? i went with using `datetime ` instead

Comment: @TabAlleman SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported. The best option would be to upgrade. Other than that - just add the quotes by hand

Comment: @lizzy81 I would either delete the question, or edit it to clarify that the issue involves using the Execute Stored Procedure in SSMS, and the question is why don't the single quotes get automatically added for the Date datatype.   But if 2008 is no longer supported by Microsoft, there will probably never be an answer to this question.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: SSMS 2012 is still supported ;)

Comment: Re "how do i handle this question" – posting your solution (workaround) as a self-answer would seem the best option. I don't know if many people use the "Execute Stored Procedure..." interactive feature of SSMS, but if this is indeed a bug as it appears to be, your answer would certainly help others in a similar situation.

Comment: I've edited your question to add an important point that was established in the comments. Please take a look and edit further as necessary (if necessary).

Comment: This is still a bug in SSMS 2012.  I use the right-click > "Execute stored procedure..." command all the time when developing stored procedures and I avoid the "date" type for this reason.  I use "datetime" instead.  It's a bug, it's annoying, and MSFT should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to posters here, this may be a bug and since 2008 is no longer supported, (and i dont have the option to upgrade) my best solution was to use a `datetime` instead of `date`.

Comment: Uh, or just put quotes around the date value, instead of changing your stored procedure...

Comment: it was just more foolproof to change to `datetime`. in the event that someone else uses the stored proc, they wouldnt know to add the quotes

Comment: How often are your users really executing stored procedures manually by right-clicking the name in Object Explorer? And if a user put quotes around a datetime value (did you try that?), and gets a different error, will you change it back? Which set of users will you prefer? Maybe the real solution is to ***stop using that dialog***.

Comment: its a stored procedure that populates another table. only time it will be used is during maintenance. i understand the point your trying to make but running a failed stored proc just to put quotes and run it again isnt worth the hassle.

Comment: I understand the problem (the GUI has a bug where it puts quotes around datetime values but not date values), but what is the right fix? Expecting users to add single quotes, or hoping they don't? Go ahead, try putting quotes around the datetime parameter (which most people will know to do!) in that Mickey Mouse dialog, and tell us what happens when you execute. Again, maybe the real solution is not using a buggy dialog in the first place. And I have confirmed this issue still exists in the very latest builds of SQL Server 2016, so this isn't going to go away once you finally get off of 2008.

Comment: well the "fix" was switching to datetime. as ive tried to explain, their are no users. i just need to enter a date and run it. no need to waste time with 2 extra characters. if you mean adding it to the stored procedure, `where date = '@date'` wouldnt work since @date would be treated as a string

Comment: The users I was referring to is what you said earlier: `in the event that someone else uses the stored proc`. Also, waste time with two extra characters? It's a date, not a number, you shouldn't be trying to avoid delimiting it properly. This fix is a terrible idea. The fix is to stop using a buggy dialog to execute the procedure.

Comment: how else do i execute it then?

Comment: Type in a query window: `EXEC dbo.CalenderPreload @startingSunday = '20151227', @numberOfYears = 5;` - and yes, you'll need to type those excruciatingly painful single quotes there.